# Best way to ease in a Widget with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation

I'm working on an app that can display a "no connection" widget at the top of it when internet is lost. Since my app doesn't have a "forehead" part per-se, I'm just adding a widget to the tree (to be more precise, I make an appBar appear).

The problem with that solution is that even with the use of `ShowUpAnimation`, when the widget appears, the space is taken instantly. This displaces all the elements brutally, it looks pretty choppy and bad. Here's what it looks like, pardon my literal french:

[image: bad looking pop-in]

I'm looking for a solution to this problem that would allow me to ease-in that widget with a transition that pushes the rest of the screen down gently over a certain duration so it looks smoother. Additionally, my current solution doesn't handle widget exit, it just disappears which is even more jarring.

Thanks in advance !

Code:

How the app bar is called in the Scaffold:

```
appBar: !viewModel.hasConnection
              ? const PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(35),
                  child: NoConnectionAppBar(),
                ) : null
```

`viewModel.hasConnection` is automatically updated with a Stream.

How the app bar is implemented in the class:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShowUpAnimation(
        curve: Curves.linear,
        offset: -0.5,
        child: AppBar(...)
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use an `AnimatedContainer` instead the `AppBar` and place it above all other Widgets. This gives the advantage that the height can be animated, so the other Widgets are sliding down with the space the `AnimatedContainer` uses.

more information see here: [AnimatedContainer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedContainer-class.html)

Comment: I'm trying to implement that currently but I'm having issues with using a column with a bottom navigation bar and an `IndexedStack`

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IndexedStack-class.html this example shows an `IndexedStack` within a `Column`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the `AppBar` you should consider using something like `SliverAppBar` it has the `expandedHeight` property where you can set its **height** and change it on event. 
**Keep in mind** that `SliverAppBar` should be put inside *scrollview* with `slivers` property. For example -- `CustomScrollView`

More information about: 
[SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html) (official) 
[CustomScrollView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html) (official) 
[unofficial guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-add-sliverappbar-to-your-flutter-app/) which you might find helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer, there were two cases:

In the first case, the bar needed to take some vertical space on the screen. So I removed the appBar, and instead wrapped the `Scaffold` in an Expanded and then in Column. In the controller, I defined a variable named `topBarWidget`. When the controller gets created, we initialized that widget to either my no connection bar or to a 0 height SizedBox. We also hook up this logic to the function that handles connection detection.
Finally, I added an `AnimatedSize` widget on top of the Column with that topBarWidget as the child. Works great, make sure the Column is wrapped in a safe area though.

In the second case, I actually found I didn't need my widget to take vertical space, so I just added the same logic in the controller to define a topBarWidget.
Then, I wrapped that topBarWidget in an `AnimatedSwitcher` with a transition builder that used a `SizeTransition`.

You will find the code the result. Thanks @dstreissi for putting me on the right tracks.

[image: look how smooth it is]

1 - Taking up vertical space

```
SafeArea(
    child: Column(
        children: [
            AnimatedSize(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                curve: Curves.easeIn,
                child: viewModel.topBarWidget,
            ),
            Expanded(
                child: Scaffold(...),
            ),...,
);
```

2 - Stacking up on the Z-axis

```
SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              ...
              body: Stack(
                children: [
                  SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [...],
                    ),
                  ),
                  AnimatedSwitcher(
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                    transitionBuilder: (Widget child,
                    Animation<double> animation) => SizeTransition(sizeFactor: animation, child: child,),
                    child: viewModel.topBarWidget,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

Notice how I put the ScrollView inside the Stack so that my noConnection message would stay on top of the screen even when scrolling down.